# How to create and submit Dynamic table which has rowspan - JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a webpage where a user can create a dynamic table, user can also add groups, and add genre in the group and add movies according to the genre. An example of my data is below:

[my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uEjc.png)

Currently I only know how to create a dynamic row on a button click, my JQuery script is:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#my_button").click(function(){                                                     
         $("#my_table").append('<tr><td><input type='text'></td><td><input type='text'></td></tr>');
     });
   });
```

and my **HTML** code is a simple table with a button in the end:

```
<table class="my_table" id="my_table">
  <tr><td>Movie Name</td><td>IMBD</td></tr>
</table>

<button id="my_button">Add row</button>
```

so my next steps are, to add a button which says Add Genre which should add a row and change the rowspan of the parent **"Group 1"** row to rowspan++

**How do I do this?**

After this, once I have all the features to create the dynamic table, I want to submit the data and store it in a MySql database, and in order to create the SQL query, I need to know what is the rowspan value of group and Genre, so my next question is, how do I send the value of rowspan in a form post?

Also, the reason for giving such a detailed explanation of my chain of thoughts is  that if you think there is a simpler solution to solve the problem then you are most welcome to suggest :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#my_button").click(function(){                                                 
         $("#my_table").append('<tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>');
     });
   });
```

In you code you have to keep you html tag in **"** instead of **'** in html tag attributes.
Write html tag attribute like **type="text"** .